# What does this Java 8 stream code mean?

Tags: java, java-stream

```
boolean isA2Z(String str) {

        return (str.chars().filter(i -> i >= 'a' && i <= 'z').distinct().count() == 26);
    }
```

From the method name, it looks like it tests whether a String contains letters from a->z, but it doesn't look right?

It collects individual characters from the string and then return the count of the stream. How can this work?

Comment: Stream the chars, filter only a-z, non duplicates, and count... see if == 26 meaning all the English alphabet is there...

Comment: It tests whether every letter in the alphabet is present at least once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.chars()` --> returns `IntStream` for characters in String

`filter(i -> i >= 'a' && i <= 'z')` --> Filtering and it allows only [a, z] (inclusive) to go on next processing function

`distinct()` --> get all distinct values

`count()` --> count the items made their way through here.

functionally it checks if the String contains all the small [a, z] (inclusive) atleast once. (avoiding corner cases here)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it works, step by step:

1. Convert string to list of individual characters
2. Exclude any characters not between 'a' and 'z' (inclusive)
3. Create a unique list of remaining characters
4. Count the number of unique characters
5. Return true if the number is 26; return false otherwise

In other words, the method returns true if and only if the input string contains at least one occurrence of every lowercase letter from a to z.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say if string is following

"abbcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

This method will return true. Method is checking whether string contain all alphabets from a to z regardless if they are repeating.